# What's the correct way of having a GCP account without a GSuit account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google, google-cloud-identity

My organization doesn't use GSuit but we still want to use the Google Cloud Platform. I signed up there with my non-gsuit email address and I have a GCP account I can log in to.

There are two issues that I'm seeing, which might be related. When I try to invite other members of my organization with their non-gsuit non-gmail email addresses I get this error:

> Email addresses and domains must be associated with an active Google Account or Google Apps account.

How do I invite them to be a Google or Google Apps account?

The project I created seems to belong to no organization:

[image]

What's the correct way to have this set up for a non-gsuit company?

When I go to `IAM & Admin` > `Identity and Organization`, I see this:

[image]

When I try to sign up for Cloud Identity, I eventually get to this screen:

[image]

which feels like I'm signing up for GSuite, which I'm not interested in (but I'm not sure if that's the case).

If I try to sign up, I get this error:

[image]

I had to create that account to be able to start using the Google Cloud Platform, but now I'm blocked from creating an Organization? This is a tad confusing.

If I go to manage users or groups, this is what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to enable Organizations to use Google Cloud.

To enable users to use your Google Cloud Platform, they will need a Google Account. This is not the same as a Google G Mail account or Google G Suite account.

Have the new users create an account. Then add them to your Google Cloud Platform using IAM.

[Google Accounts](https://accounts.google.com)

You can also use Google Identity Platform to manage users. This also supports creating a Google Cloud Platform Organization.

[Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/)

Comment: Thank you John. I'm still trying to understand what's the right way to set this up. I updated the question with a bit more information. So, it's possible to have a Google Cloud Platform Organization without using GSuite, correct? It is not possible to invite users to the cloud project without them having an account before hand, is that correct? Would having a Google Cloud Platform Organization allow me to create accounts for other users?

Answer (score 1):

The [Organization resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#organizations) is closely associated with a G Suite OR Cloud Identity account so if you want to use organization without using G suite the only way is to use  [cloud Identity](https://cloud.google.com/iam/).

Also, it is not possible to invite users to the cloud project without them having an account before. You need to have an account through cloud identity. Cloud Organization is just used to manage your GCP resources among the users in your organization and not used to create or setup an account.